# how can i use TestNg assertion method in for loop

Tags: java

i have 2 excel sheets, i am comparing cell values using testNg Assertion.
following are the values in sheet1 and sheet2

```
Sheet1  Sheet2
sachin  sachin
david   david
nancy   nancy
winter  winter

  int rowCount = xlib.getRowCount("Sheet1");
  int rowCount1 = xlib.getRowCount("Sheet2");

    for (int i = 34; i<=rowCount;i++)
    {
        String compair1= xlib.getExcelData("Sheet1", i, 5);
        System.out.println(compair1);

            for (int j = 34; j<=rowCount1;j++)
            {
                 String compair2=xlib.getExcelData("Sheet2", j, 5); 
                        System.out.println(compair2);
                        Assert.assertEquals(compair1, compair2);
```

System.out.println("compared successfully");

```
            }   
    }
}
```

}

Result:-

```
sachin
sachin
compared successfully
david
FAILED: Totalcompare
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [david] but found [sachin]
```

Expected result
Result:-

```
sachin
sachin
compared successfully
david
david
compared successfully
nancy
nancy
compared successfully
winter
winter
compared successfully
passed: Totalcompare
```

Comment: You shouldn't have two loops. Just one. And for each row, you want to compare the value at that row in sheet1 with the value of that row in sheet2. Currently, you comparing each row of sheet1 with each row of sheet2.

Comment: i am bit confused here, can you please help me with re- correcting my code?

Comment: I have already. Have you read my comment?

Comment: i have read your comment but , i am not able to make the changes in my code, Can you please paste the code , one more time, appreciate your help!!

Comment: Sorry, but this is really something that you should be able to figure out by yourself, especially with the help I already provided. What don't you understand? What have you tried? I said: you shouldn't have two loops, just one. So, what do you conclude regarding what you should do?

Comment: Now, I got it. Thanks .  Appreciated